# Diff tool for Visual studio that's impervious to minor reformatting?

Tags: formatting, diff

Is there a diff tool that can **ignore** minor reformatting changes? For instance, moving a `{` sign on the next line.

Sometimes the auto-formatting of the IDE makes sweeping changes across a file and I'd like to be able to only see the non-trivial changes highlighted.

For instance, here's how trivial changes make KDiff light up :

[image]

I'd like a tool where I can toggle showing these as changes. Maybe even a way to teach the tool what I consider "trivial changes", possibly using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I have found one such tool: [Compare++](http://cmpp.coodesoft.com/main/features)

It understands the file structure of C# (what I needed) and other (C/C++, Java, C#, Javascript, CSS) languages, and can thus skip highlighting semantically irrelevant changes.

[image]

Unfortunately it's not free (~30 USD), but it does offer 30 days of free evaluation.